# Keep column name when select one column from a data frame/matrix in R

Tags: r

In R, when I select only one column from a data frame/matrix, the result will become a vector and lost the column names, how can I keep the column names?
For example, if I run the following code,

```
x <- matrix(1,3,3)
colnames(x) <- c("test1","test2","test3")
x[,1]
```

I will get

```
[1] 1 1 1
```

Actually, I want to get

```
     test1
[1,]     1
[2,]     1
[3,]     1
```

The following code give me exactly what I want, however, is there any easier way to do this?

```
x <- matrix(1,3,3)
colnames(x) <- c("test1","test2","test3")
y <- as.matrix(x[,1])
colnames(y) <- colnames(x)[1]
y
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `drop` argument:

```
> x <- matrix(1,3,3)
> colnames(x) <- c("test1","test2","test3")
> x[,1, drop = FALSE]
     test1
[1,]     1
[2,]     1
[3,]     1
```

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use `subset`:

```
> subset(x, select = 1)

     test1
[1,]     1
[2,]     1
[3,]     1
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions 'matrix or dataframe' as an input. If x is a dataframe, use LIST SUBSETTING notation, which will keep the column name and will NOT simplify by default!

```
`x <- matrix(1,3,3)
colnames(x) <- c("test1","test2","test3")
x=as.data.frame(x)
x[,1]
x[1]`
```

Data frames possess the characteristics of both lists and matrices: if you subset with a single vector, they behave like lists; if you subset with two vectors, they behave like matrices.
There's an important difference if you select a single
column: matrix subsetting simplifies by default, list
subsetting does not.
source: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators for details