# Display only one value in selectInput in R Shiny app

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny

I am trying to dynamically populate the values of the `selectInput` from the data file  uploaded by the user. The `selectInput` must contain only numeric columns.

Here is my code snippet for `server.R`

```
...
idx <- sapply(data.file, is.numeric)
numeric_columns <- data.file[, idx]
factor_columns <- data.file[, !idx]

updateSelectInput(session, "bar_x", "Select1", choices = names(numeric_columns))
updateSelectInput(session, "bar_y", "Select2", choices = names(factor_columns))
...
```

Corresponding `ui.r`

```
 ...
 selectInput("bar_x", "Select1", choices = NULL),
 selectInput("bar_y", "Select2", choices = NULL)
 ...
```

The code works fine as long as there are more than one values in any dropdown. However, it fails as soon as it encounters only one value to be displayed in the `selectInput`.

How can I handle this specific condition, given that the data is uploaded and it cannot be controlled if there is just one column as numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info: Code was adapted by OP to make error reproducible.
To solve your issue use `val2 <- val[,idx, drop = FALSE]`
You dropped the column names by subsetting the `data.frame()`.
To avoid this use `drop = FALSE`; see [Keep column name when select one column from a data frame/matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325688/keep-column-name-when-select-one-column-from-a-data-frame-matrix-in-r).

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
# drj's changes START block 1
        #selectInput('states', 'Select states', choices = c(1,2,4))
        selectInput('states', 'Select states', choices = NULL)
# drj's changes END block 1
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({


#drj's changes START block 2
    #val <- c(1,2,3)
    #names(val) <- c("a","b","c")
    #updateSelectInput(session, 'states', 'Select states', choices = names(val[1]))
    val <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("_1","_2","_3"), c(4, 4, 6)))
    names(val) <- c("a","b")
    val$b <- as.numeric(val$b)
    idx <- sapply(val, is.numeric)
    val2 <- val[,idx, drop = FALSE]
    updateSelectInput(session, 'states', 'Select states', choices = names(val2))
#drj's changes END block 2
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have updated your code with few modifications. It breaks at my end now. Hopefully you will be able to reproduce the issue now.

Comment: works as expected. The only thing I don't understand is that if the code is run manually in console without the `drop` argument, it does give me the expected name for column. My best guess is, that passing it as an argument in a reactive code block is not the same.

Comment: hmm, i cant reproduce that, doesnt work in console either for me

Comment: can i still help here? Otherwise i would appreciate an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in 2019, this issue still exists. The issue that I have seen is that when there is only one option in the dropdown, the name of the column is displayed instead of the one option.

This appears to only be a graphical problem, as querying the value for the selectInput element returns the correct underlying data.

I was unable to figure out why this problem exists, but an easy way around this bug is to simply change the name of the column so that it *looks* like the first element in the list.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("siExample",
    label = "Example Choices",
    choices = list("Loading...")),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # load some choices into a single column data frame
  sampleSet <- data.frame(Example = c("test value"))

  # rename the set if there is only one value
  if (length(sampleSet$Example) == 1) {

    # This should only be done on a copy of your original data,
    # you don't want to accidentally mutate your original data set
    names(sampleSet) <- c(sampleSet$Example[1])
  }

  # populate the dropdown with the sampleSet
  updateSelectInput(session,
    "siExample",
    choices = sampleSet)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```